# После ключевого слова return не выходит из функции JS

Tags: javascript, return

Есть функция:

```js
function checkAnswer() {
  const x0 = document.querySelector('#x0_answer').value;
  if (x0 !== '') {
    var arr = x0.split('');
    arr.forEach(n => {
      if (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(n)) && n.toString() !== '.' && n.toString() !== ',') {
        alert('bad');
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

После return не выходит из цикла и функции (несколько alert на экране). Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Данный цикл так не работает.. обычный for...in  и for...of - да, forEach перебирает всё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно проверить на то, что все элементы соответствуют условию, то проще воспользоваться методом **[every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**. Пример:

```js
console.log([1,2,3].every( el => el !== 1 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr.forEach(n => {`

Выходит из lambda (анонимной) функции.. )))

```
function checkAnswer() {
    const x0 = document.querySelector('#x0_answer').value;

    var BreakException = {};

    try {

        if (x0 !== '') {
            var arr = x0.split('');

            arr.forEach(n => {
                if (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(n)) && n.toString() !== '.' && n.toString() !== ',') {
                    alert('bad');
                    throw BreakException;
                }
            });

        }

    } catch (err) {
        if (err !== BreakException) throw err;
    }
}
```

Или как альтернатива использовать

```
for (let n of arr) {
   if (isBad(n)) return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `for` вместо `forEach`. В данном случае `return` выходит из `forEach`.

```js
function checkAnswer() {
  const x0 = document.querySelector('#x0_answer').value;
  if (x0 !== '') {
    var arr = x0.split('');
    for(const n of arr) {
      if (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(n)) && n.toString() !== '.' && n.toString() !== ',') {
        alert('bad');
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте вместо `forech` метод - `some`. Она проверяет, чтоб хотяб раз выполнилось условие, короче и чище код:

```
function checkAnswer() {
    const x0 = document.querySelector('#x0_answer').value;

    if (x0 !== '') {
        var arr = x0.split('');

        const bad = arr.some(n => !Number.isInteger(parseInt(n)) && n.toString() !== '.' && n.toString() !== ',');

    if (bad) {
         alert('bad');
    }
  }
}
```